maximum value of the function :$\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\sqrt{\cos(2x)}$
what is the maximum value that
$f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\sqrt{\cos(2x)}$
can have
I found that
$\max(f(x))=\max(\sin(x)+\sqrt{\sin(2x)})=\max(\cos(x)+\sqrt{\sin(2x)})$
but i can't solve this question (high school knowledge)

You can use the mean inequality between arithmetic mean and power 4 mean. Possibly you need to use a weighted mean to get a constant in the 4th powers.

The maximum doesn’t have a closed form. Can you use a graphing calculator?

focusing on one period, find the 2 roots of the derivative.. One is local max, the other is global one

no i can't use a graphing calculator. it is for high scool. but a tough one @AspiringMat

sorry i didn't mention it is for high school. i tried o find the points where derivative equals zero but it lead to sloving this: x^4-4x^3-2x^2+1=0 but i guess this can not be solved without a calculator @YvesDaoust

derivative needs solving this : x^4-4x^3-2x^2+1=0  is there a more simple derivative ?@GBmath

Numerically, the maximum value is $2.1595458034991273$, which occurs when $x \approx 0.31091415321545707$.  I don't know if there's a closed form solution, though.

Note that $f(0) = 2$, so $\max f \ge 2$.
Plugging in other “special” angles, we get $f(\frac{\pi}{12}) = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt[4]{3}}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 2.15535$, giving a slightly better lower bound on the maximum.
